# asp.net login web page using sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

i am stuck in my login page..my button click event is as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)         
{               
    string cs = "Data Source=ims-aab46237892;Initial Catalog=Inventory;Integrated          Security=True";                      

    string SelectString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = @Username AND password = @Password";           

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);         
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectString,con);         
    cmd.Connection = con;         
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;         
    cmd.CommandText = SelectString;          

    SqlParameter username = new SqlParameter("@Username",SqlDbType.VarChar,50);                   
    username.Value = TextName.Text.Trim().ToString();                   
    cmd.Parameters.Add(username);           

    SqlParameter password = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);                      
    password.Value = TextPass.Text.Trim().ToString();                      

    cmd.Parameters.Add(password);                      
    con.Open();  

    if(cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null)                 
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");            
     else                
        Response.Redirect("wrongpasspage.aspx");              

    con.Close(); 
}
```

and my data table has the required username and password fields.. error i am getting is incorrect syntax near keyword user... plz help

Comment: Potential duplicate. Please see my post here:

 - [ASP.NET Login with SQL Server Database - LINQ-To-SQL, Entity Framework, and Publish/Subscribe event pattern][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397268/asp-net-login-with-sql-server-database

Answer (score 3):

user is a reserved keyword in SQL server. Try [user] or rename your table to Users.

Comment: its working now. but regardless of any username or password. i am directed to home.aspx

Comment: Copy and paste the value of SelectString from your debugging window into SQL server and run the query, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

use [user] instead of user in SelectString statement.